# Creating Triggers from SNMP TRAP

Tags: zabbix

Im having the following SNMP coming in from the snmptrap.fallback. I want to create a trigger which should do the following

```
2023-07-10 05:38:47 2023-07-10 05:38:45 
09:38:45 2023/07/10 PDU INFO:
  receivedfrom                   UDP: [10.22.11.72]:52862->[10.22.5.22]:162
  messageid                      0
  transactionid                  299
  requestid                      0
  notificationtype               TRAP
  errorindex                     0
  community                      zabbixcommunity
  errorstatus                    0
  version                        0
VARBINDS:
  DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance type=67 value=Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
  SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0      type=6  value=OID: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.0.6031
  SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0          type=4  value=""
  SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.11.2.11.1.0 type=2  value=INTEGER: 0
  SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.6.2.9.3.1.1 type=2  value=INTEGER: 0
  SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.6.2.9.3.1.2 type=2  value=INTEGER: 0
  SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB::snmpTrapAddress.0 type=64 value=IpAddress: 10.22.11.72
  SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB::snmpTrapCommunity.0 type=4  value=STRING: "zabbixcommunity"
  SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapEnterprise.0 type=6  value=OID: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232
```

It should go positive if the below are positive using an **AND** Operator

1. value=OID  equals 6031
2. Integer value for enterprises.232.6.2.9.3.1.1 equals 1
3. Integer value for enterprises.232.6.2.9.3.1.2 equals 1

As Im new to zabbix can someone guide me how to go about this.